# How to confirm email and set new password for a user using devise in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

In my application a user is created by admin setting a default password.After, a mail is sent to the user to confirm mail id and to set password. User will feel , first time a password is creating.

```
Confirm e_mail:
Enter Password:
Confirm Password:
```

I am using devise 3.5.2 and rails 4.1.6. How i can i customize the device default view and how can i handle this situation together.Now i can handle the e-mail confirmation only.

Can u pls help..Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you are looking for this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation

Answer (score 0):

Generate devise views by

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Following folders create after that

```
app/views/devise/confirmations
app/views/devise/mailer
app/views/devise/passwords
app/views/devise/registrations
app/views/devise/sessions
app/views/devise/shared
app/views/devise/unlocks
```

Then customize their devise default views